# Google Maps API won't print, need alternative

Tags: google-maps

Can anyone recommend an alternative map to the google embed api map that will print?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapquest is able to be embedded, and has a print option.

```
http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/add-a-map-to-your-website
```

Comment: Thank you.  I started using mapquest and it does print, but the address hardly ever shows up.  So far it's been 2/6 addresses work on map quest.  The api was easy to use...

Comment: Thanks for the update, there are other options. I checked for locations here too:

Comment: Yahoo is going to Nokia for their map service, 'here maps' and so I found this link: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HERE_Maps_API_-_Add_Maps_To_Any_Web_Page

Comment: Bing has a map interface too, but I did not readily see a print icon on the setup page. Regardless, and if I just did not see the print option, the setup link I found is here: http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/SnippetGenerator.aspx?src=O365